# How do I make a samba server in a virtualbox VM automatically save/overwrite to another hard drive when changed

Tags: hard-drive, samba, ubuntu-22.04

I'm using samba for a NAS on my home server and I have 2 drives and I want to make it possible to save/overwrite to another drive whenever something is changed/access on the drive. I am using 2 2TB drives.
(I don't know if I'm on the wrong stackexchange please tell me if so)

Comment: Do you mean a sync, a backup or a RAID?

Comment: @mashuptwice backup to 2nd drive.

Comment: Have a look at [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync)

Comment: @mashuptwice is there any other way?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/148665/is-it-possible-to-sync-two-linux-directories-in-real-time

Comment: Note that any solution which automatically backs up any changes to a different location, will also sync any defective files. A solution like this will be no replacement for a backup.

Comment: @mashuptwice how do you suggest I do this then?

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is that you have a look at different backup strategies, check your requirements and select one that fits your needs. After that have a look which software you can use to accomplish that, not the other way around